# error code -207 during import of certificate using GnuTLS

Tags: certificate, x509, c++, error-handling

I try to import a certificate, to process it in my C++ code. What am I doing wrong? Here are the steps I perform in my code:

I initiate with `gnutls_global_init()`

I get a FILE-type opject into my programm, `using fopen and fread`

I save the FILE-type obejct containing the certificate and the length of the FILE-type into a gnutls_datum_t-type object (loaded_file)

I init a gnutls certificate with `gnutls_x509_crt_init(&cert)`

I use `gnutls_x509_crt_import(cert, &loaded_file, GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM)`

I get the error code `-207: Base64 unexpected header error`...what does this mean?
when I want to print the certificate information using gnutls_x509_crt_print() I get the following information:

cert[1424]:

> X.509 Certificate Information:
>
> Version: 1
>
> error: get_serial: ASN1 parser: Value was not found.
>
> Issuer:
>
> Validity:
>
> ```
>    Not Before: Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 UTC 1969
>     Not After: Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 UTC 1969
> ```
>
> Subject:
>
> error: get_signature_algorithm: ASN1 parser: Value was not found.
>
> warning: signed using a broken signature algorithm that can be forged.
>
> error: get_signature: ASN1 parser: Value was not found.
>
> Other Information:
>
> error: get_fingerprint: ASN1 parser: Value was not found.
>
> error: get_key_id: ASN1 parser: Value was not found.

---

The certificate I am trying to import is a selfsigned certificate created with certtool.

what is wrong in my import-chain?

Comment: Looks like the certificate you're trying to import isn't signed. Are you sure it's not simply a certificate request ?

Comment: when I look up the properties, it says that my certificate is a X.509-Certificate. This looks to me to be a valid certificate to import it into gnuTLS format, right? Further more it is self-signed. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: Check the certificate format (PEM, DEM) and expected by function

Comment: The certificate format is PEM and as you can see above the expected format is also PEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I got the same error code.
In my case I used the wrong buffer and tried to load the private key instead of the certificate using gnutls_x509_crt_import.
It seems that the error code -207 is generic for "I didn't find any license".

So if this error occurs, you should always check the input buffer for correct data.